# Is there a library or framework for creating annotations with nifty arrows and handwriting?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, annotations, usability

Recently you can find this in lots of apps:

When the app starts the first time, it explains the interface with nifty arrows and handwriting letters.

Does anyone know of a library or framework which can draw these arrows and handwriting labels in a easy way?

To clarify: I will need about 20 different arrows. That is why I want to draw them programmatically instead of including 40 PNG files (low-res, high-res).

Comment: What do you mean? Create an arrow in Photoshop and animate it. Create a font or find a good font that replicates handwriting and type it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done tutorial animations using [AIAnimationQueue](https://github.com/aitskovi/animation). It doesn't do much, but it does allow you to string together a sequence of animations.